# Preload Solution while blazor wasm starts

Tags: blazor-webassembly, webassembly, preload, .net-7.0

The first time a blazor wasm app is executed it downloads the necessary data into the client.
This may take a while.

So i want to show the user something(plain html or somthing quick) instead of this preloading page.

[image: Blazor wasm downloading content]

Comment: i think the question is prety acurated, how can i change that preload screen

Comment: Have you searched for blazor prerender?